# Mono on Ubuntu, Issue with Visual Studio DLLs

Tags: .net, mono, ubuntu-12.04

I'm not sure if my description is the best.

I have a project built with VS2012/13 on Windows/.NET which I've brought over to an Ubuntu box running Mono (the latest version).

I'm getting this error, and I'm not sure what it's telling me, or how to fix it:

Missing method System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException::.ctor(HttpStatusCode) in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Http/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Http.dll, referenced in assembly /home/ubuntu/node-servers/NodeProcessorHost/native/BatchEmailSend/Profiles.Client.dll

Note that this is running via EdgeJS (hence the Node references), but that it runs fine on Windows/EdgeJS.

So, it's two questions really:

- What is the root cause of this message?
- How do I fix it?

Comment: I have possibly solved this by setting MONO_PATH so that a necessary dll was found.  It seems mono was looking in the gac (the last place it checks) and not finding it.  The message was a little confusing because of the nested assembly, but it seems to be passed now...

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful of differences in System assemblies between platforms.  Messages about vacant constructors (ctor) maybe an indication of an improper or missing assembly.  One way to ensure your assemblies are found is to set the MONO_PATH to include their location.

In this situation, that worked for me.